# Messaging with Laravel: Get one common field value of different rows by searching only one or two keywords

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a messaging feature for my Laravel website to allow users to message each other.

Here's my tables so far.

## Table: participants

| id | thread_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 12 |
| 2 | 8 | 24 |

## Table: threads

| id | topic |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | ABC |

## Table: messages

| id | thread_id | user_id | body |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 12 | Hello! |
| 2 | 8 | 24 | Hello too! |

In my **Thread** model:

```
public function participants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Participant::class, 'thread_id');
    }
```

In my **Participant** model:

```
public function thread()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class, 'thread_id');
    }
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

In my **Message** model:

```
public function thread()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class, 'thread_id');
    }
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

What I want to accomplish is this.
There are two given user_ids, **my user_id** *(the current logged in user)* and **the target user_id** *(the person I want to message)*.

1. How can I get the thread_id that me and the target user have in common?
2. And what's the efficient way or method to do this?

I already tried all the available packages in Github like the [Laravel Messenger](https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger?) but I can't get it to work plus it is designed for multiple conversations. I've spent whole day searching google for a similar problem and solutions but I'm not getting any relevant results. I guess I'm probably using the wrong keywords.

What I need is a simple private messaging between two user. So I decided to create one that fits my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this query? (not tested)

```php
$threadIds = Thread::whereHas('participants', function ($query) use ($authUserId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $authUserId);
})
->whereHas('participants', function ($query) use ($targetUserId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $targetUserId);
})
->pluck('id');
```

This is the query builder version if you want better performance

```php
$threadIds = DB::table('threads')
    ->join('participants as p1', function ($join) use ($authUserId) {
        $join->on('threads.id', '=', 'p1.thread_id')
             ->where('p1.user_id', $authUserId);
    })
    ->join('participants as p2', function ($join) use ($targetUserId) {
        $join->on('threads.id', '=', 'p2.thread_id')
             ->where('p2.user_id', $targetUserId);
    })
    ->pluck('threads.id');
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! Your second code is perfect!